# HP Z400 workstation with RHEL5 LINUX OS; NO MORE REACHABLE, need to reboot

Tags: linux

The LiNUX RHEL5 Workstation Z400 stop answering to ping and it was no more possible to connect to it, even on the local console; The workstation was not reachable in anay way.
The only method I found is to restart the station (switch off, switch on) and after that everything works fine
Have somebody an idea on what can have happened
I don't see explanation of this in the /var/log/messages

Some more informations:
Placement/routing of a FPGA was running

I have often this problem with Z400 system hang; The last time , there was quite a little activity on this Workstation BIOS Information

```
Vendor: Hewlett-Packard
Version: 786G3 v03.12
Release Date: 09/13/2010
Address: 0xE0000
Runtime Size: 128 kB
ROM Size: 2048 kB
```

lsb_release –a

`LSB Version: :core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-ia32:graphics-3.1-noarch Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer Description: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Boron) Release: 5.5 Codename: Boron`

I had contact with HP but for the moment no explanation discussion, about Samba configuration... But as the problem does not occur systematically...

Comment: So you're saying the console was non-responsive as well, so it's not a network issue. Is there anything that was written to the console/stout? Is this regularly happening/reproducable? If it regularly happens, is there any way you can leave it at a non-graphical screen to see if there's some kind of kernel dump of errors?

Comment: Yes, everything is frozen; this happen sometimes; I don't know where i can try to find any informations abou the problem,nothing interesting in teh /var/log/messages, i only see informations while restarting the system; People that where using the system remotly only see that tey can't do anything

Comment: This question belongs on SuperUser or Linux/Unix

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like normal-ish behavior when the processor is too busy to service normal requests.
Try renicing the process doing the routing to a lower priority, or perhaps try setting CPU affinity, and try and free up a core for processing GUI and ethernet interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

Did this occur during the flashing process on the FPGA? If so, you may be causing the crash or system hang at that point. Is this repeatable?

Comment: This occur while running the process of routing the FPGA; it happens many times but not every time and I don't know where to search, I don't see anything in the var/log/messages. It did not happen while flashing the FPGA

Comment: while doing the place and route process for the FPGA; the tool from provider crash and after that no possibility to do anything; the tools is customized to use all the 4 processor's core to do the place and route